# How can I plot a smooth line over plot points, like a contour/skyline of the plot?

Tags: r, plot, max

What I'm looking for is best explained by a picture: A line that "contours" the maxima of my points (like giving the "skyline" of the plot). I have a plot of scattered points with *dense, (mostly) unique x coordinates* (not equally distributed in either axis). I want a red line surfacing this plot:

[image: a plot that contours the maximas of a plot]

What I've tried/thought of so far is, that a simple "draw as line" approach fails due to the dense nature of the data with unique x values and a lot of local maxima and minima (basically at every point). The same fact makes a mere "get maximum"-approach impossible.

**Therefore I'm asking: Is there some kind of smoothing option for a plot? Or any existing "skyline" operator for a plot?**

*I am specifically NOT looking for a "contour plot" or a "skyline plot" (as in Bayesian skylineplot) - the terms would actually describe what I want, but unfortunately are already used for other things.*

Here is a minimal version of what I'm working with so far, a negative example of `lines` not giving the desired results. I uploaded sample data [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nkk0me442gqhhte/xy_lidarProfiles.RData?dl=0).

```
load("xy_lidarProfiles.RData")
plot(x, y, 
          xlab="x", ylab="y", # axis
          pch = 20, # point marker style (1 - 20)
          asp = 1 # aspect of x and y ratio
)
lines(x, y, type="l", col = "red") # makes a mess
```

[image: this is not what I want but get when using R lines]

Answer (score 1):

You will get close to your desired result if you `order()` by x values. What you want then is a running maximum, which `TTR::runMax()` provides.

```
plot(x[order(x)], y[order(x)], pch=20)
lines(x[order(x)], TTR::runMax(y[order(x)], n=10), col="red", lwd=2)
```

[image]

You may adjust the window with the `n=` parameter.

Comment: Nice solution.  More generally, if the local max isn't what you want (e.g. it's not smooth enough), the `zoo::rollapply` function can find other local envelopes.